# yii - select first five records for each type field ordered by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with following fields:

```
Advertisements (
  id bigint 20,
  name varchar 255,
  content text,
  creator_id bigint 20,
  type_id bigint 255 DEFAULT VALUE IS NULL,
  create_date bigint 20
)
```

I need to select first 5 records by each type ordering them by date (I need latest ones). Also I want to use the result with `CActiveDataProvider`. Is there any ways to get the records using model function or yii integrated function except sql queriers (Cause: I also need relations provided in Advertisements class)?

**UPDATE**
Other tables:

```
Users (
  id bigint 20,
  login varchar 255,
  password varchar 255,
  email varchar 255,
  date_of_registration bigint 20,
  status varchar 255
)
(The table with types)
Items (
  id bigint 20,
  item varchar 255,
  link varchar 255
)
Comments (
  id bigint 20,
  creator_id bigint 20,
  ......
  topic_id bigint 20
)
Rating (
  id bigint 20,
  creator_id bigint 20,
  ......
  topic_id bigint 20
)
```

I want to have latest records for each `type_id` in advertisements ordered by `create_date` if the number of records exceeds 5 for one type then select only latest 5. Also I want to have login of the creator + number of comments + rating table fully? I know that is solveable by SQL, but I do not have any ideas how to do it because I am not good at SQL. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for everyone who tries to help.

Comment: Possible using SQL (although not fast). but would even bother considering trying to do it in yii active records or the like.

Comment: Try checking Yiis' CDbCriteria.

Comment: @SnIpY could you help me to manage with this problem. BTW I know about CDbCriteria.

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a set of Googling according the hint of James K. Lowden I fount the next answer:

```
SELECT t.id,
        t.name,
        t.content,
        i.item,
        c.context
FROM (SELECT tbl.id,
            tbl.name,
            tbl.content,
            tbl.owner_id,
            tbl type_id,
            CASE 
                WHEN tbl.type_id = @category THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                ELSE @rownum := 1
            END AS num,
            @category := tbl.type_id
        FROM Advertisements tbl
        JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @category := NULL) r
        ORDER BY tbl.type_id, tbl.create_date DESC) t
LEFT JOIN Items i ON t.type_id = i.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments c ON c.topic_id = t.id
WHERE t.num <= 5
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right something like this should work (not tested). You should have an index on (type_id, date)

```
// Extract unique types. Perhaps you have table `type` and should do this other way but since you provided info only on Advertisements table I'm using what I got
$types = YII::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT DISTINCT type_id FROM Advertisements;")->queryColumn();

$resultsAll = array();
foreach ($types as $type_id) {
    $results = Advertisments::model()->findAll(
            array("condition" => "type_id = $type_id", "order" => "date DESC", "limit" => 5)
    );
    $resultsAll = array_merge($resultsAll, $results);
}

$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($resultsAll, array());
```

Comment: I wonder, if I can do all of this in one query, because I have about 8 types in my database, so I think it would be not optimal solution to perform too much queries. But thanks for help +1 from me.

Comment: It's quite complicated to do with one query and I don't know if it is even possible with ActiveRecord query. This article discusses the problem http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *by each type*, or why you don't want to use SQL to do what SQL was designed for.

If you use the [canonical query](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows) to rank your types,

```
select a.id, a.name, a.content, 
       a.creator_id, a.type_id, count(b.id) as Rank
from Advertisements as a join Advertisements as b
on    a.id = b.id
and   a.name = b.name
and   a.content = b.content
and   a.creator_id = b.creator_id
and   a.type_id >= b.type_id
group by a.id, a.name, a.content, a.creator_id, a.type_id
having count(b.id) <= 5
```

and Advertisements is indexed by the columns in the GROUP BY clause, the query should run in *O(n log n)* time.  In most cases that's indistinguishable from *O(n)*, which is hard to beat.

If you're concerned with performance, you might want reconsider the column sizes.  I don't know what `bigint 20` is, but a MySQL bigint is 64 bits.  Do you really expect more than 4 billion creators or types, and are you sure the name has to be more than, say, 30 characters or so?  All these choices can be changed later if the one you make now is too restrictive, but too-large choices will degrade performance from Day 1.

Comment: I tried your query, it selects all the records in the table. Are you sure you dont have mistakes?   There is no problem in usage of SQL, firstly I was searching the way the result to be available in CActiveDataProvider with all the relations, but now I think it is impossible to do with default model functions. SQL is ok, if it selects with related tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use CDBCriteria. Example:

```
function actionIndex()
{
    ...
    $_criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $_criteria->order = 'create_date DESC';
    $_criteria->limit = 5;

    $_ads = new CActiveDataProvider('Advertisements', array('criteria' => $_criteria));

    ...

    $this->render('index', array(
        ...
        'ads' => $_ads,
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: it will query last 5 records ordered by date, but I need last (number of types)*5 records where each 5 records are the latest ones in each type in the table